# How to run a function in the terminal everytime a key is pressed(bind the whole keyboard)

Tags: bash, shell, readline, bash-completion, libreadline

I have been playing with bash for the past week and would like to create a function that is called every time I press a key on the keyboard.
I read about bind but it forces me to bind to a specific key.
If anybody can assist me I would appreciate it

I would like to accomplish this without new shells like zsh or fish

Comment: Personally I can't think of one good reason I'd want a function to trigger with each and every key press, so I'm curious as to specifically what you're attempting to do and why?

Comment: I would like to implement my own  kind of auto completion that doesn't require <Tab> or any key. the function will call a service on my machine and will get back some options

Comment: That's interesting.  Thanks for illuminating the issue however I'd stick with normal tab completion.